# promise data not getting assigned to console variable angularJs

Tags: angularjs

I am using angular in saleforce VF and getting data from apex controller.

Below is the concerned code:

```
function Quote_Details_Ctrl($scope,quoteDetailsFactory){
            console.log('Inside Angular Controller');
            $scope.quoteData = [];
            $scope.quoteId = "{!$CurrentPage.parameters.quoteId}";
            console.log('quoteId : ' + $scope.quoteId);
            $scope.loadData = function(){
                var promise = quoteDetailsFactory.loadData($scope.quoteId);
                console.log('promise : ' ,promise);
                promise.then(function(obj){
                    $scope.quoteData = obj;
                    console.log('obj : ' ,obj);
                },[]);
            console.log('quoteData : ',$scope.quoteData);
            }
            console.log('Hi Controller ');
        $scope.loadData('quoteData2 : ',$scope.quoteData);
        }
```

when I print obj in console, it prints the data correctly. However, when I assign it to the scope variable and console the scope variable, it shows as an empty object with no data.

Can someone please tell if something is missing.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you think loadData() returns a promise of data, rather than simply returning he data directly? Read https://blog.ninja-squad.com/2015/05/28/angularjs-promises/

Answer (score 1):

`$scope.quoteData` has to be accessed within the promise resolve function

```
$scope.loadData = function(){
        var promise = quoteDetailsFactory.loadData($scope.quoteId);
        console.log('promise : ' ,promise);
        promise.then(function(obj){
            $scope.quoteData = obj;
            console.log('obj : ' ,obj);
            console.log('quoteData : ',$scope.quoteData);
        },[]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the time when the statement `console.log('quoteData : ',$scope.quoteData);` executes, the promise hasn't yet resolved.

What you can do is either access this variable from the `.then()` function only, or you can call another function when this promise is resolved

```
 promise.then(function(obj){
     $scope.quoteData = obj;
     console.log('obj : ' ,obj);
     $scope.helperFunc(obj);
 },[]);

$scope.helperFunc(quoteData) {
    console.log("Here you can get the quoteData: " , quoteData)
}
```